# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 - OpenGL

Tags: c++, zlib

When I try to compile some C++ code in Code::Blocks, I get these errors:

```
 "_inflate", referenced from:
      InflateFile(__sFILE*, __sFILE*)in ZLibDecompressor.o
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      InflateFile(__sFILE*, __sFILE*)in ZLibDecompressor.o
  "_inflateInit_", referenced from:
      InflateFile(__sFILE*, __sFILE*)in ZLibDecompressor.o
  "_sws_getContext", referenced from:
      RiffMovie::ParseFile(char const*)in RiffMovie.o
  "_sws_scale", referenced from:
      RiffMovie::PlaceRGBData()      in RiffMovie.o
```

I am trying to compile this on Mac OS X 10.8 x64.

Comment: I got the OpenGL working, but now I have these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inform linker that you want to use OpengGL.framework. To do so, add "-framework OpenGL" flags in options.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Where is "options"?

Comment: It's here http://www.noquarterarcade.com/system/files/images/code_blocks_linker_options.png